# How do I get the last part of directory from a command line

Tags: windows, files, batch-file, directory, strings

How do I store the last part of directory in a variable?

For example I have the following path: `A\B\C\D`, I want to store `D` in variable like `file_name=D`.

Comment: You might have more joy with this over on SuperUser (http://superuser.com/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because of your Windows tag, I assume your `cmd.exe` has extensions built-in.  If that is the case, you can use two of `FOR`'s special substitution variable references:

Given a variable `%A`, containing a path and file:

`%~nA` will output the file name, `%~xA` will output the file extension.  The following example uses the pipe character `|` as a delimiter.  The pipe is an invalid character for files and paths  and should *not* appear in a path. This will allow for spaces in paths and filenames.  See `FOR /?` for full details.

```
C:\> SET FSPATH=C:\WINDOWS\Temp\file.txt
C:\> echo %FSPATH%

C:\WINDOWS\Temp\file.txt

C:\> FOR /F "delims=|" %A IN ("%FSPATH%") do echo %~nxA

file.txt
```

Alternatively, should you not have extensions in your `cmd.exe`, you can use `delims=\`, count the directory separators and split your path/file string based on that number.

**Edit:** Per your comment about the error. Above is an example *on the command line*.  If you want to perform the same *within* a batch script, you need to double the `%` on the the variables:

```
FOR /F "delims=|" %%A IN ("%FSPATH%") do echo %%~nxA
```

To use the value outside of the `FOR` loop, you would need to assign the value to another variable. The variable `%%A` is limited to the scope of `FOR`.

```
:: example.bat
SET FSPATH=C:\Windows\bfsvc.exe
FOR /F "delims=|" %%A IN ("%FSPATH%") DO (
    echo Inside loop %%~nxA
    SET SOMEFILE=%%~nxA
)

ECHO Outside loop %SOMEFILE%
```

Comment: i try it but the following error appear :- `SPATH~nxA was unexpected at this time.`

Comment: this does not work for me. the `FOR` line echos the correct part of the path but after this the `%%~nxA` does not get expanded and is passed just as the string "%%~nxA".

Comment: @vlad_tepesch My bad, updated answer with correction about variable scoping outside `FOR`.

Comment: @jscott thanks - i just got it with the help of the other answer. It is possible to keep this a one liner by omitting the echo and directly do the set.

Comment: This doesn't work if the path ends with a slash.

Answer (score 2):

Give this a try:

```
for %f in (A\B\C\D) do set var=%~nxf
```

Comment: this error appear :- `~nxf was unexpected at this time.` `C:\Program Files\GNU\>for ~nxf`

Comment: @MohammadAL-Rawabdeh: You said "from a command line". If you're doing it in a batch file, you'll need to use double percent signs.

Comment: sorry ... i want execute it from batch file :- it will be %~nxf%

Comment: @MohammadAL-Rawabdeh: No. `for %%f in (A\B\C\D) do set var=%%~nxf`